# How to combine image map area class with alt attribute to make new class

Tags: jquery, html, css, attr, imagemap

I have an image map with each of 21 states in the US as a separate area. Example:

```
<area class="region" shape="poly" coords="66,8,138,27,126,80,103,73" alt="WA">
<area class="region2" shape="poly" coords="60,15,108,87,26,120,100,53" alt="CA">
```

Right now I have it set up so that each state area has it's own class and when clicked, opens a div (class .wa or .ca in the example below) with info for that state.

```
$('.region').click(function(){
    $('.wa').show("scale", 350);
});

$('.region2').click(function(){
    $('.ca').show("scale", 350);
});
```

But that requires repeating a lot of code. What I would like to do is combine ("bind"?) the alt attribute of the image map area to the class so that I don't have to repeat the jQuery code for every state region on the image map.

**Pseudocode:**
 When clicked, region class + "alt" -> opens the div that matches the new class.

in other words

.region (the class) + WA (the alt) -> .regionWA which would open the div with the class .regionWA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
$('.region').click(function() {
    var state = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('.region' + state).show('scale', 350);
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly! I never even thought about assigning the alt to a variable! I was really overcomplicating it. Thanks SailorLeroy!